# Recursion for a classification tree problem in r for an s3 class

Tags: r, binary-tree

I am writing a class (s3) that should use a constructor to create an instance for the class, at least for a start. The constructor `junction(name, left, right)`. Where `name` is the description of a node in a classification tree.

So I have a class called `junction` having 3 entries as indicated above.

```
junction <- function(name = character()) {
  left = NULL
  right = NULL
  value <- list(name = name, left = left, right = right)
  attr(value, "class") <- "junction"
  value
}
```

`left` and `right` correspond to the tree's next left and right node but becomes `NULL` at the leaf node. I need to define the constructor above correctly so that I can create a leaf node. Then I am trying to write a simple print method that works recursively to produce the following sample;

```
junction("Tom", junction("Wendy", junction("Jane"), junction("Nancy")), junction("Ellen"))

Tom
+- Wendy
| +- Jane
| +- Nancy
+- Elen
```

So are there any ideas on how I would write the `print.junction(obj, some_str, ...)` I am adding `some_str` here thinking that it might probably help with the recursion - to provide the string before the output on the current node. There are ideas of these kinds of recursions for java and even c++, but I can't find anything R related.

Comment: Your example throws an error, shouldn't the constructor have 3 arguments like in `junction <- function(name = character(), left = NULL, right = NULL)`?

Comment: The constructor as it is will throw an error; that is why I need a print method that will do some recursion around each name. e.g. `junction("Nancy")` But as you've noted, the constructor might not be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your consturctor to something like

```
junction <- function(name = character(), left=NULL, right=NULL) {
  value <- list(name = name, left = left, right = right)
  attr(value, "class") <- "junction"
  value
}
```

Then you can define a recurvsive print statement

```
print.junction <- function(x, nested=FALSE) {
  adorn <- function(v) if (length(v)>0) {
    paste0(c("+-", rep("| ", length(v)-1)), v)} else {c()}
  r <- x$name
  child <- c()
  if (!is.null(x$left)) {
    rl <- print.junction(x$left, nested=TRUE)
    child <- c(child, adorn(rl))
  }
  if (!is.null(x$right)) {
    rr <- print.junction(x$right, nested=TRUE)
    child <- c(child, adorn(rr))
  }
  if (!nested) {
    cat(c(r, child), sep="\n")
  }
  invisible(c(r, child))
}
```

So when you call

```
junction("Tom", junction("Wendy", junction("Jane"), junction("Nancy")), junction("Ellen"))
```

You get

```
Tom
+-Wendy
| +-Jane
| +-Nancy
+-Ellen
```

The idea is a straightforward recursive approach. You keep calling the function adding in special marks for each level of nesting.